# Rules of Inference with Quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having confusion in using the inference rules with quantifiers. For example:

1. ∀x (Man(x) → Mortal(x))
2. Man(Socrates) → Mortal Socrates(x)  By Universal Instantiation
3. Man(Socrates)  by Premise
4. Mortal(Socrates)  By Modus Ponens from step 2 and 3

How do you get the third step? I understand you would need it to use Modus Ponens but how can you write it as a premise and from where did that come from?

Comment: What are you trying to prove ? [All Men are Mortal. Socrates is a Man. Therefore, Socrates is Mortal.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism) Fullstop.

Comment: The third step is a Premise (as you have written). Also step 1 is a Premise, and step 4 is the Conclusion.

Comment: Your second line should be Man(Socrates) $\to$ Mortal(Socrates).   Man(Socrates) is a ***premise***: meaning it is a given, along with $\forall x$(Man(x) $\to$ Mortal(x)).  So by modus ponens from 2, 3, you get Mortal(Socrates).

Comment: Well, that makes sense. I also had another problem. Example: C(a) ∧ ¬B(a), how does that become C(a) using simplification?

Comment: See [Simplification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a premise. You cannot logically deduce that Socrates is a man - but it is something you assert as part of your proof i.e. a premise. Just like you assert all men are mortals.

1. All men are mortals (Premise)
2. Therefore if Socrates is a man, he is mortal (UI 1)
3. Socrates is a man (Premise)
4. Socrates is mortal (MP 2,3)

Comment: Well, that makes sense. I also had another problem. Example: C(a) ∧ ¬B(a), how does that become C(a) using simplification?

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it satisfactorily answered your question :)

If C(a) and NOT B(a) are true, then C(a) is true. I am a man AND a student therefore I am a man. Just a trivial statement in logic.

Comment: But wouldn't the simplification law only work if p ∧ q therefore p? If q is a negation the statement itself would result in a false right? So how can that be a p then?

Comment: The q part doesn't matter. But okay, I am (a man) and NOT (a dancer) therefore I am a man

Comment: And yes, if q is itself p, then q ^ - q is false, so if you use the rules of inference on a false statement, you get garbage out :)

Comment: So basically when using the simplification law, I exclude the q part, right? And what would happen if p was negated instead of q? Would the result be the negation of p?

Comment: Take a minute and think - this stuff is blindingly obvious once you get around the symbols. I am a man and not a dancer ... so am I a dancer?

Comment: you won't be a dancer. But wouldn't it be the other way around? I am not a man and a dancer if p was negated instead?

Comment: I am confused about your question. Whenever you have a AND b, then a is true and so is b. a and b can be as complicated as you like. (anything) ^ (anything else) -> anything  /   (anything) ^ (anything else) -> anything else

Comment: What i am trying to say is that the simplification rule only worked when there was no negation. But for the problem I asked about C(a) ∧ ¬B(a) being C(a) you said the q part doesnt matter. But what if for the same question the p was negated? So it would be ¬C(a) ∧ B(a). What would that result to using the inference law?

Comment: Yes, it always works. If you have ANYTHING ^ SOMETHING  then ANYTHING is true and SOMETHING is true. ANYTHING could be C(a). It could be NOT C(a) it could be ((T(a) OR NOT(G(a) AND S(a))) AND (K(a) OR H(a))).